# how to add a stickers pack in Telegram from an exsternal android app i made?

Tags: java, android, telegram

I already made an usual Whatsapp Stickers app for android Now I wonder how made the same but for Telegram I would like to make an app where I add the same Stickers pack on Whatsapp and Telegram with 2 diffent buttons Then what is the java code to add an stickers pack in Telegram ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user client with any telegram library available for java.
Then send message to @Stickers.